# Why is the Unix community allowed to vote for or against a potential merge of Ubuntu and Unix, but not the Ubuntu community?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In the unix.stackexchange.com site a banner pops up to vote for or against the merge of unix.stackexchange.com and ubuntu.stackexchange.com. However, here on the ubuntu site this banner does not pop up.

This is absolutely unfair. Besides, that this vote is unnecessary, because this choice has already been made in the proposal phase, any voting should be done in a fair and equal way.

Democracy is not voting until the desired result can be achieved, if necessary by means of unequal situations!

[The voting link is here](https://askubuntu.com/polls/1/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-merge)

Answer (score 5):

the "vote on unix vs ubuntu" was inserted into the message queue of all accounts with >= 15 reputation with users who have been active in the last 30 days, excluding moderators

Comment: Ah, excluding moderators explains it. Thanks!

Comment: >= 15 rep, active in past 30 days *and* with >= 3 up-votes. I fail eligibility on that last criterion. =/

Comment: Ah.. thank you Jeff for this clarification

Answer (score 1):

If the banner didn't come up, you can still -presumably- follow the URL from the [Should Unix Linux and Ubuntu be Merged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-be-merged-vote/) blog entry, just to satisfy my completist fetish:

- Ubuntu community vote: https://askubuntu.com/polls/1/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-merge
- Unix community vote: https://unix.stackexchange.com/polls/2/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-merge

Answer (score 0):

The voting banner came up for me on the Ubuntu site.

It looks like if you click the [X] on the voting banner on one site, then it won't show up for you on either site.

Comment: well.. it shouldn't they are two different votes

Comment: I saw it too, and voted.

Comment: ok.. then it is fine... I did not get a banner

Answer (score 0):

Where is a vote to close both unnecessary and redundant sites?  SOI has succeeded in fracturing the Ubuntu SOI community now to **FOUR** SOI sites: SuperUser, ServerFault, Unix SE, and Ubuntu SE.

Questions about Ubuntu get answered in SECONDS on ServerFault and SuperUser.  Here, they don't get answered at all.  Why would we want to expend effort convincing people to come here when they're already there, asking and answering Ubuntu questions?  I'd rather see all of you back on SU and SF participating in the ACTIVE community there rather than fracturing the users among four different sites.

Already, one needed to post the same question in two places just to get answers from everyone active on an SOI site.  I can't reasonably bring myself to cross-post to four SOI sites when it's already debatable whether cross-posting is permitted.

Of course, creating separate posts on different SOI sites for the same question shouldn't be necessary in the first place. The user and question namespaces should be merged such that a question and its answers can easily appear on several sites, and such that users are able to participate, search, and interact across the spectrum of SOI sites without need to repeat the same activities on all sites.  If that were done, it wouldn't be so bad to have extra SOI sites like this.

Comment: If someone cross-posts unnecessarily, mods could vote to kick it out of one of the extra SOI sites it was posted to.

Comment: Why don't you ask on the site you believe you get the fastest and best answer? If you look in my profile at stackoverlow, you find lots of tumbleweeds, I am not sure if any question here even got to tumbleweed stage yet.